# SP2010: Kick-Off Workflow via a Windows Service

Tags: spservices, service

I know triggering workflows within SharePoint can be started manually/automatically? In the realm of being fired off automatically, I know capabilities of starting workflows if documents are added to a library or a link is clicked. I am inqusitive to know that are workflows able to be triggered by services, moreso a Monitoring Service?

Comment: do you want to trigger the workflow if a field item exceeds some specific value?

Comment: Not necessarily, in the grand scheme of things, the goal I am trying to achieve is I have a web application that has certain requests (RequestA, RequestB, and RequestC). If RequestB and C are chosen, a monitoring service running ever X minutes will poll the application and verify that these items are the ones that need to be sent to SP for Approval, which will then fire off a SharePoint approval workflow for these requests. Was this description clear?

Comment: an idea would be to write the result of the poll into a sp list an check the results which are now stored in a list via a workflow... this would be a pragmatic approach of course but may be it will fit your needs..

Comment: Awesome! I just asked one of the architects about a few things. I belive I can develop a Windows Service application to make this come to fruition

Comment: please mark as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an idea would be to write the result of the poll into a sp list an check the results which are now stored in a list via a workflow... this would be a pragmatic approach of course but may be it will fit your needs..